# How to insert a row into a table for every userid

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In MSSQL I have a table `codes` with columns `userid` and `code`. There are many rows in a table already like

```
userid | code 
1      | A
2      | A
3      | B
4      | A
4      | B
```

I would like to insert B in code column for every `userid` that doesn't have it. in my examle it would be for userid 1 and 2.

How to dynamic insert this?

```
INSERT INTO 
    codes (userid, code) 
VALUES 
    (1, B), 
    (2, B);
```

Expected result is:

```
userid | code 
1      | A
1      | B
2      | A
2      | B
3      | B
4      | A
4      | B
```

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can try using the following `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO codes (userid, code)
SELECT userid, 'B'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM codes) t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM codes c
    WHERE c.code = 'B' AND
          c.userid = t.userid
);
```

The subquery aliased as `t` will generate a unique set of all `userid` across the entire table.  Some kind of distinct operation is needed, as a given missing `userid` for code `B` could appear more than once across other codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EXCEPT operator:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.codes (userid,code)
SELECT DISTINCT userid, 'B' as code
FROM dbo.codes 
EXCEPT
SELECT userid,code
FROM dbo.codes
WHERE code='B';
```

Answer (score 1):

While this answer is logically equivalent to the [WHERE NOT EXISTS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73609467/659190), you should favour that answer because the [LEFT JOIN may exhibit poorer performance in non trivial cases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/best-practice-between-using-left-join-or-not-exists).

```
INSERT [codes]
SELECT
          L.[userid],
          'B'
    FROM
          [codes] L
       LEFT JOIN
          [codes] R
              ON R.[userid] = L.[userid] AND R.[code] = 'B'
    WHERE
          [R].[userid] IS NULL;
```